# How to take the backup of Database in MSSQLSERVER2008 with Encryption

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am using MSSQLSERVER2008,
and i am trying to take the backup of a database using following command,

```
'BACKUP DATABASE <DatabaseName> TO DISK='<path to take the backup>''
```

i want to take the backup with Encryption but the above commands give me the backup file only.
in the path or location that i specified.

Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in backup encryption.  You would need to enable Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) for the backups to be encrypted.  There is no other way to do this through SQL Server.

[Here's a reference explaining so.](http://chrisshaw.wordpress.com/2009/05/18/sql-server-2008-backup-encryption/)